# Windows 8 App using COM dlls of Sharepoint gives error "Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Web.Services.dll'"?

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, web-services, client-object-model, windows-8

I have created a sample app using Windows 8 C# XAML to get site info of SharePoint 2010 using COM Dlls. I have added reference of:

> 1. C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\SharePoint Client\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
> 2. C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\SharePoint Client\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

but when I build the project it gives me following error:

> Error1: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file
>   'System.Web.Services.dll' E:\Windows 8 And Sharepoint
>   Example\SharePointCOMApp\SharePointCOMApp\SharePointCOMApp.csproj
>
> Error2: Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Web.Services,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  SharePointCOMApp

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember to my experiences with *W8* vs. *SP 2013 / O365*, Managed Client Object Model assemblies (like *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll*) cannot be directly referenced from a Windows Store App. Include your code into a wrapper class implemented as *Class Library (Windows Store Apps)*, and reference this one from your Windows Store App.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are targeting the wrong version of the .Net framework - you need the full framework and not the Client Profile.